# HTTP status code in downloading derivative files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I would like to know two things about [an API to download a derivative file](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-derivativeurn-GET/):

- Is there any case in which I get status code 206 (PARTIAL CONTENT) when I send a request without specifying Range in header?
- If the answer is YES, what is the reason (e.g., the requested derivative file is too large)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will double-check with the dev team but I believe that the status code 206 is *only* returned when requesting a specific range.

Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/206):

> The HTTP 206 Partial Content success status response code indicates
>   that the request has succeeded and has the body contains the requested
>   ranges of data, as described in the Range header of the request.